# Fulltext search

Tags: mysql, full-text-search, yii

I'm trying to get full text search working in Yii and I can't seem to find the issue.

I have the following SQL statement working correctly.

```
SELECT * FROM Topic WHERE MATCH(title,content) AGAINST ('testing' IN BOOLEAN MODE) LIMIT 11;
```

In Yii, I'm using the following critieria that appears to be returning `SELECT * FROM Topic LIMIT 11;`

```
CDbcriteria Object
(
   [_paramCount:private] => 0
   [select] => *
   [distinct] =>
   [condition] =>
   [params] => Array
      (
      )

   [limit] => 11
   [offset] => 0
   [order] =>
   [group] =>
   [join] =>
   [having] =>
   [where] => Array
      (
         [0] => MATCH (title,content) AGAINST ('testing' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
      )
)
```

Any ideas where I've gone wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe the fulltext search should be placed in "condition", not "where".

I usually use the function [addCondition](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbCriteria#addCondition-detail) to accomplish this.